# Copy a Trello board, keep columns and cards, but loose card contents (comments etc)

Tags: trello

Is it possible to copy a Trello board, keep all the columns and cards, but loose all the card contents (eg. comments, descriptions, checklists etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the board into template.

Creating templates from boards
Boards of all visibilities within Business Class and Enterprise teams can be turned into templates. Additionally, any public board--whether personal or part of a team--can be converted to a template.

- From the Board Menu, select More and then select Make Template. (You must be an admin of the board to see this option.) Turning the board into a template will hide comments and activity, but members will remain on the template.

https://help.trello.com/article/1187-creating-template-boards

Comment: Can this be done on a standard account or on a paid account only ?

Comment: it seems it can be done with standard account.